# Neo4j NeoVis trouble

Tags: javascript, neo4j

i have some trouble using NeoVis.js to visualize my Neo4j-graph.

I use the Movie-Tutorial-Database in which i established relationships "ACTED_WITH" between everone who acted in a movie together. All of my stuff is local.

I made a test.html file in which is following code:

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DataViz</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #viz {
            width: 900px;
            height: 700px;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://rawgit.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js/master/dist/neovis.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var viz;
        function draw() {
            var config = {
                container_id: "viz",
                server_url: "bolt://localhost:7687",
                server_user: "Neo4j",
                server_password: "123",
                labels: {

                    },
                relationships: {

                },
                initial_cypher: "match (tom:Person{name:"Tom Hanks"})-[r:ACTED_WITH]->(coWorkers)
                return tom, r, coWorkers"
            },

            viz = new NeoVis.default(config);
            viz.render();
        };
    </script>

</head>

<body onload="draw()">
    <div id="viz"></div>
</body>
```

And when i open the file in my browser it shows the title inside the tab an thats it. Investigating it with the browser tools it shows the following:

test.html:30 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

test.html:41 Uncaught ReferenceError: draw is not defined
    at onload (test.html:41)

I dont get it. draw() is defined, isnt it? And the query works fine within the Neo4j-browser too. 
Can you figure out whats wrong? Thanks in advance.

Greetings

Comment: your code is working for me with minor changes. Still are you getting exception

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code..

The cypher works for me, First test with some simple cypher to test whether you are connecting to neo4j using bolt.
Then add your cypher check proper syntax too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" data-semver="2.0.3" data-require="jquery"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js/master/dist/neovis.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function draw() {
    alert("inside method");
    var viz;
var config = {
            container_id: "viz",
            server_url: "bolt://127.0.0.1:7687",
            server_user: "Neo4j",
            server_password: "password",
            labels: {

                },
            relationships: {

            },
            initial_cypher: "MATCH (n:Movie) RETURN n LIMIT 1"
        },

        viz = new NeoVis.default(config);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(viz));
        viz.render();
       };
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<div id="row2">
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="draw()">
<div id="viz"></div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I get the notification windows "insode method" on click. But still nothing gets drawn.

Comment: Are you getting anything on `console.log(JSON.stringify(viz));`

Comment: I get a websocket connections failure. When i set my browser (Vivaldi) to allow all websocket connections i get 2 errors:

GET file:///home/konster/Dokumente/Spa%C3%9F%20mit%20Graphen/NeoVisGed%C3%BCdel/style.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.

I cant find anything :(

Comment: Can you once try without adding style.css . Whether u will get query executed or not

Comment: Can you please check whether this line is uncommented... `dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687`

Comment: Check with adding 'encrypted: "ENCRYPTION_ON",` inside config